# Rails 3.1 ckeditor gem. Ckeditor resources loading on every page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, ckeditor, asset-pipeline

I am using the ckeditor gem and i am using it on one page of my website.  When i use Apple Safari's web inspector I am noticing that ckeditor resources are loading on every page. Any ideas on how to limit this.  I'm running it in development mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add more details if you want help here. For example:

- Which gem are you using?
- What procedure have you used to include ckeditor?
- Which Rails version are you using?

Anyway I guess you placed the `//=require ckeditor` instruction in your `application.js` file, which is include in the layout view, so in every page of your app, if you didn't change the layout settings.

You just need to move the instruction in another `.js` file and include it just in the page where you need ckeditor.

See [this gem documentation](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) for more information.

Comment: Yes,  I am using the gem you linked to.  Do you think the performance hit is significant enough to take it out of the application.js file?  Is it still considered a pipeline asset if the reference is changed?  How does this affect precompilation?

Comment: Well.. I can't give you a clear answer about the performance hit, you should use the Network tool of the inspector to find out how much time it requires and make your choice.

Comment: It is pipeline as long as it is in the assets folder and there is a directive to load it. If you remove the //=require ckedito then you need to add the file to the pipeline by adding in your application.rb this line: config.assets.precompile += ['editor.js']. Where editor.js is a file where you have inserted the //=require ckedito

Comment: Precompilation should not be affected by this. The line added in the application.rb just tells Sprockets, which is the one building up the pipeline, to add the file in it when you run bundle exec rake assets:precompile